# how to use polymer starter kit doc & demo offline?

Tags: web, gulp, polymer, components

i have installed polymer starter kit 1.3.0, Using gulp serve i can access index.html located in app folder at localhost:5000.

i have two questions.

1) My question  is how to access pre-developed components located at /bower-components/ on web browser?

i have tried to install and serve gulp in /bower-components/,but it still serve the /app/index/

i am not able to access components references on web browser.

2) After complete development how to host it without gulp, ex. on xampp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Python's HTTP server](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to serve up the `bower_components` directory, allowing you to access the subdirectories offline:

1. Open a terminal into `bower_components/`
2. Run: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to start an http server on port 8000.
3. Open a browser to **http://localhost:8000/{dir}**, where `{dir}` is the directory name of the component you wish to view (e.g., **http://localhost:8000/paper-ripple/**).

Answer (score 0):

I think in the starter kit, bower_components directory is mapped to the /components url when you use gulp serve.  This is the same url as your app/elements directory.

This is designed so that you app-elements can access polymer by a url of ../polymer/polymer.html (and similarly for the other elements)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. `bower_components` is not mapped to any other directory.